# Minimizing required area and finding the value of the parameter

Tags: calculus, area

If we have a function:
$$f(x)=x^3+3x^2+x+a$$ where $a$ is a parameter such that the area bounded by $f(x)$, the $x$-axis and the ordinates ie. lines parallel to $y$-axis at the points of extremum of the function is minimized. We have to find the value of $a$.

Now, my first step was to find the values of $x$ at which extremum occurs by putting $f'(x)=0$ which gave $x=-1\pm \frac{\sqrt6}{3}$.

Now I realized by the graph of $f(x)$ that all $a$ does is move the curve up or down so if $|a|$ is too large the area covered will increase so the best case scenario has to be for $f(\frac{x_1+x_2}{2})=0$ where $x_1,x_2$ are the extrema points that I calculated above. So I got the value of $a$ using this.

Now my question is if there is any alternate approach without the use of graphing where we can prove that $f(-1)=0$ rigorously? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I think it's risky to take such an approach. My intuition says that this kind of approach cannot always be true. The function would have to be antisymmetric with respect to the point $(x_1+x_2)/2$. So how I would approach this, is that since I know the integration limits, just evaluate the integral and set that to be a function of $a$. By the way, is the area a **signed** area?

Comment: @MattiP. No I think it's unsigned. Signed means that you take area below $x$-axis -ve right? I don't think that has to be done here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you wish to minimize the quantity:
$$I_a=\int_{-1-\frac{\sqrt6}{3}}^{-1+\frac{\sqrt6}{3}}(x^3+3x^2+x+a)$$
You can evaluate this integral and find:
$$ I_a=[\frac{x^4}{4}+x^3+\frac{x^2}{2}+ax]_{-1-\frac{\sqrt6}{3}}^{-1+\frac{\sqrt6}{3}}=\frac{2\sqrt6}{3}(a+1)$$
$I_a$ is now a function of $a$. Actually, you're really interested in minimizing $|I_a|$ since I assume you don't care about the sign of the area. It's easy to see that you can minimize $I_a$ by choosing $a=-1$, since $I_a$ is a non-negative function of $a$, but by choosing this value of $a$ you get that it's $0$ (and so it cannot get any smalller)